# User defined data type that uses another user defined data type as a parameter

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting the compiler to accept my below defined user data type (Term) that accepts another user data type (Rational) as a parameter.  Any suggestions on how to make this work would be great!

```
#ifndef _TERM_H
#define _TERM_H

#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;

class Term {

public:

    //constructors
    Term( const Rational &a, const int &b)
    { 
        this->coefficient = a;
        this->exponent = b;
    }

    Term(){}

    ~Term () {}

    //print the Rational
    void print()const 
    {
        cout << coefficient << " x^"  << exponent << endl;
    }

private:

    Rational *coefficient, *a;
    int exponent, b;
};

#endif
```

---

```
#ifndef _TERM_H
#define _TERM_H

using namespace std;

class Rational {

public:

    //constructors
    Rational( const int &a, const int &b){
        if (a != 0)
            if (b != 0)
                this->numerator = a;
            this->denominator = b;
    }

    //print the Rational
    void print()const {
        cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << endl;
    } 

    //add 2 Rationals 
    void add(const Rational &a, const Rational &b){
        numerator = ((a.numerator * b.denominator)+(b.numerator*a.denominator));
        denominator = (a.denominator*b.denominator);  
    }

 ...

    private:
     int a, b, numerator, denominator;
};

#endif
```

I keep getting the below error messages.

Term.h(30) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const Rational' to 'Rational *'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It makes it a lot easier for us to read it and help you.

Comment: NEVER use `using namespace std;` in a header. For that matter, never use a `using xyz::abc;` either! Each file that includes this header will be prone to namespace conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the definition of `coefficient` to this:

```
const Rational& coefficient;
```

Then change the constructor to this:

```
Term (const Rational& a, const int& b)
  : coefficient (a), exponent (b)
{
}
```

Comment: Okay redid the Term class and added an overloaded  operator  for '=', however it is still giving me flack, any ideas? See below:

Comment: class Term {

public:
 
 Term (const Rational& a, const int& b)
 : coefficient (a), exponent (b)
 {
 }


 //Term(){}

 ~Term () {}    

 //coefficient
 void setCoefficient(const Rational& a){
  coefficient = a;
 } 
 
 string getCoefficient()const{
  return coefficient;
 }

 //exponent
 void setExponent(const int &b){
  exponent = b;
 } 
 
 string getExponent()const{
  return exponent;
 }

 //print the Term
 void print()const {

  cout << getCefficient << " x^"  << getExponent << endl;
 } 
 
private:
 const Rational &coefficient;
 //Rational *a;
 int exponent, b;
};

#endif

Comment: Okay. . . I can't read the above code myself.  What I was trying to show is that I followed your suggestion and changed the way my constructor is set up. I also added an overloaded operator :

Comment: Term.h(46) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Rational' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        c:\users\kbpersonal\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\cmis_315_final_proj\cmis_315_final_proj\Rational.h(37): could be 'Rational Rational::operator =(const Rational &)'
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(const Rational, const Rational)'

Comment: Is my overloaded operator in the Relational class okay?                                                                       Rational operator =( const Rational &r )
 {
  this->numerator = a;
  this->denominator = b;
  return *this;
 }

Comment: Change all types in the class that are `const Rational&` to `Rational&`. That should solve the problem. Oh and `operator=` should return a reference.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is, that `Term::coefficient` has type `Rational*` (pointer to Rational) and in constructor you are trying to assign a value of type `Rational` to that member variable.

So the correct constructor would, if you want to keep the rest intact, like this:

```
Term(const Rational& a, int b) : coefficient(&a), exponent(b) {}
```

Or you can leave constructor intact and change the private section:

```
private:
    Rational coefficient;
    // the rest of the member variables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print() const 
{
    cout << *coefficient << " x^"  << exponent << endl;
}
```

Are you not missing a dereferencing operator there?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the same include guard name (`_TERM_H`) in two different header files.  This is very bad--you need to make the include guard name unique among all files within your project, or else the inclusion of one file will block the other.  In particular, if I read your code correctly, you have this:

```
#ifndef _TERM_H
#define _TERM_H
#include "Rational.h"
```

And Rational.h has this:

```
#ifndef _TERM_H
#define _TERM_H
```

This should mean that when you include Rational.h, `_TERM_H` is already defined, so the contents of Rational.h will be ignored.